How to combine route_change and CupertinoNavigationBar in Flet?
I want it to be possible to navigate through the bottom panel between pages, and for each of these pages to be able to view information by pressing a button at the top of the screen
I was able to do each function separately, but I can’t combine it(
In my other application, I was able to combine this, but it does not work properly. Sometimes the transition may freeze
import flet as ft
from flet import *

def main(page:Page):
    page.title = "Test"
    page.window.width = 450.00
    page.window.height = 800.00
    page.window.resizable = False
    page.update()

    def chagetab(e):
        my_index = e.control.selected_index
        tab_1.visible = True if my_index == 0 else False
        tab_2.visible = True if my_index == 1 else False
        tab_3.visible = True if my_index == 2 else False
        page.update()

    tab_1 = Text('Tab 2', size=30)
    tab_2 = Text('Tab 2', size=30, visible=False)
    tab_3 = Text('Tab 3', size=30, visible=False)

    def route_change(e):

        page.views.clear()
        page.views.append(
            View(
                "/",
                [
                    AppBar(
                        title=Text("Home"),
                        center_title=True,
                        bgcolor='green50',
                        actions=[
                            IconButton(icon=icons.HELP_OUTLINE, on_click=open_settings),
                        ]
                    ),
                    CupertinoNavigationBar(
                        bgcolor=colors.LIGHT_BLUE_700,
                        inactive_color=colors.GREY,
                        active_color=colors.WHITE,
                        selected_index=0,
                        on_change=chagetab,
                        destinations=[
                            NavigationBarDestination(icon=icons.EXPLORE, label="Rules of the game", ),
                            NavigationBarDestination(icon=icons.GAMES, label="Game"),
                            NavigationBarDestination(icon=icons.TABLE_VIEW, label="Statistics"),
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        )

        if page.route == "/About the application" or page.route == "/Terms and Conditions":
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    "/About the application",
                    [
                        AppBar(
                            title=Text("About the application"),
                            center_title=True,
                            bgcolor='green50',
                        ),
                        Text("About the application!"),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            "Terms and Conditions", on_click=open_mail_settings
                        ),

                    ],
                )
            )
        if page.route == "/Terms and Conditions":
            page.views.append(
                View(
                    "/Terms and Conditions",
                    [
                        AppBar(
                            title=Text("Terms and Conditions"),
                            center_title=True,
                            bgcolor='green50'
                        ),
                        Text("Terms and Conditions"),
                    ],
                )
            )
        page.update()

    def view_pop(e):
        page.views.pop()
        top_view = page.views[-1]
        page.go(top_view.route)

    page.on_route_change = route_change
    page.on_view_pop = view_pop

    def open_mail_settings(e):
        page.go("/Terms and Conditions")

    def open_settings(e):
        page.go("/About the application")

    page.go(page.route)


ft.app(target=main)


I can't figure out how to do it better(
In my other application, I was able to combine this, but it does not work properly. Sometimes the transition may freeze
